# Frame Navigation without code-behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, navigation, frame

I am trying to create a navigation-application using Ribbon buttons (or regular buttons). When I try the following code (namespace definitions omitted)

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="/Pages/Welcome.xaml" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainFrame}">Click</Button>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"></Frame>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

the button grayed out and doesn't work. Is there anyway possible to achieve this without using code-behind or any framework?

Comment: Can you add the code you would apply in your code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway possible to achieve this without using code-behind or any framework?

No, I don't think so, apparently only `DocumentViewer` and `FlowDocumentPageViewer` (but not `Frame`) support `NavigationCommands.GoToPage` natively: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ff0906f-3847-46fe-8aff-c121e9caf655/how-to-enable-a-navigationcommandsgotopage-command?forum=wpf